# How to read and write a table / matrix to file with python?

Tags: python, matrix, file-io, tabular

I'm trying to create a program that takes data and puts it in a 2 by 10 table of just numbers in a text file. Then the program needs to retrieve this information in later iterations. But I have no idea how to do this. I've been looking at numpty commands, regular file commands, and ways to try and make a table. But I can't seem to get any of this to work.

Here is an example of the table I am trying to make:

```
0    1    1    1    0    9    6    5
5    2    7    2    1    1    1    0
```

Then I would retrieve these values. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: You have to define "table".  Is it a text file of numbers with exactly four spaces separating them?  Or is it a set of numbers left-justified inside 5 spaces.  They're not the same, unless all the numbers are single digits.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use the `csv` module?

```
table = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

import csv

# write it
with open('test_file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    [writer.writerow(r) for r in table]

# read it
with open('test_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    table = [[int(e) for e in r] for r in reader]
```

This approach has the added benefit of making files that are readable by other programs, like Excel.

Heck, if you really need it space or tab-delimited, just add `delimiter="\t"` to your reader and writer construction.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` should be enough

```
table = np.loadtxt(filename)
```

this will have shape (2,10). If you want it transposed, just add a `.T` just after the closed bracket

Comment: It's a heavy project, and unless he is doing serious math on that matrix there's really no reason to use numpy. Don't get me wrong, it's a great library.

OTOH, it does look like he's exploring the option in the question, so maybe this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

to handle the lines one-by-one:

```
with open('filename') as f:
   for ln in f:
       a = [int(x) for x in ln.split()]
```

or, to generate a two-dimensional array:

```
with open('filename') as f:
   a = [[int(x) for x in ln.split()] for ln in f]
```

Thanks Ord and Francesco Montesano for the comments

Comment: `readlines()` is not necessary and if the file is large slows down the code a lot and fill the memory. It is better to use `for ln in f:`